# Wrong decimal place in Currency Xamarin iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a Label that displays the sum of amounts as Currency:

```
List<decimal> dataAmounts = App.DashboardModel.Amounts.Where(o => Convert.ToDecimal(o.Amount) >= 0).Select(o => Convert.ToDecimal(o.Amount)).ToList();
lblPagoMinimo.Text = dataAmounts.Sum().ToString("C");
```

Where Amount is retrieved as a string (throught api call) and converted to decimal.

It displays text like it's expected in my Android phone and two phones more (We are all in the same country). Example: **$123.45**.
But there's a complaint of someone getting the Total like this **$12.345**

I was thinking this is something related to Culture but it doesn't makes sense how the decimal point in the wrong place. The only thing I know is that this error is showing in an iPhone X.

Is there a reason for this to happen? is it related to Locale Culture or...?

Comment: you need to find out what the user's locale setting is

Comment: Where can the user search for this kind of information in an iPhone?

Comment: Settings —> general —> language and region

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are using `CultureInfo` when converting double ToString.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tostring?view=netcore-3.1